# Adding a location based-microposts and map which shows user's microposts place with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4

I've already finished Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial. Now, I've got an app that users can follow the other users, create microposts and share these microposts with their followers.
Now I want to add new property to my app that sharing microposts with their locations. And also I want to add a map (like Google Map) which shows the all micropost which are sharing with their locations on the map.

I've tried many times to adding locations to my microposts but I could't be successful. Finally I had that sharing my problem with stackoverflow's users will be better.

1) I'm using sqlite for database. Is this enough for me?

2) I am not sure that add columns to microposts or create new migration file as locations?

3) And also I want to know that https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder is enough for me to make my project.

Thank you for your attentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) SQLite is probably fine until you get a lot of activity on your site. The bottleneck comes when multiple microposts are being added at the exact same time. If you anticipate massive growth and a highly trafficked site, I'd probably start using mySQL or preferably postgreSQL.

More about this here: [Sqlite3 vs Postgres vs Mysql - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322003/sqlite3-vs-postgres-vs-mysql-rails)

2) If you're storing a location, you'll likely need latitude and longtitude columns. If I were you, I'd put them directly on microposts to avoid having to query multiple tables.

3) I don't know anything about geocoder, but your only basic option when recording micropost locations is to grab the IP address and translate it into a physical location. Of course, this won't be accurate for people using a VPN or web proxy. You can also get fancy and request the location directly from a device, which is what Twitter for IOS or Android does, for example.

If this geocoder doesn't suit your needs, an alternative might be: https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails

Good luck to you!