# How to configure rails app so that local development and production deploys both working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I was coding my rails app with sqlite3 and all was fine.

Then I deployed to Heroku and had to change DB to Postgres. The only way I could get production deploy to work is by just having gem pg in the gem file, as opposed to have it in a :production group.

Anyway, when I try to configure app the following way,the app won't run locally anymore. What am I missing?

Gem File

```
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
```

and here's my db.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: I'm confused why you have a sqlite3 database declared for production if you're using Postgres? Regardless, you'll need to be sure to use the correct database adapter for each environment. `sqlite3` for sqlite3 and `postgresql` for postgres

Comment: The short answer is "don't use sqlite in development and test if you're deploying to Heroku". There are a number of differences between sqlite and postgres that may bite you later on. Better to use postgres everywhere and make your life easier.

Comment: It won't run locally b/c the default adapter is postgresql. I agree with @jvillian, best to use postgresql everywhere, including test. It's the only way your test suite gives you assurance of the production env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Production, it is working because of pg gem and postgresql adapter**

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
```

**gem file**

```
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
```

**In development it fails because of sqlite3 gem and postgresql adapter. Add right database gem. If postgresql then, gem 'pg' inside development group**

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  

development:
  <<: *default
  database: dev-database
```

**gem file**

```
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Better switch to a single database.

This link may help to choose the right DB based on your requirement.
[Sqlite3 vs Postgres vs Mysql - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322003/sqlite3-vs-postgres-vs-mysql-rails)

Comment: When I do that I now get error saying:

PG::ConnectionBad (fe_sendauth: no password supplied
):

No clue how to now resolve this

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up switching my local environment to postgres and it has made me very happy

Answer (score 1):

@praaveen's answer is absolutely correct, but just to expand slightly since his snippet of `database.yml` was just a relevant subset, not complete. In `config/database.yml` you specify the database configuration for each environment (dev, test, prod). That configuration does vary by the type of database as well, and specifically when moving from Sqlite3 to Postgres you need to change the database names, and add the username and password for each environment. So, the `database.yml` should look something like:

```yaml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: dev-database
  username: whatever
  password: whatever

test:
... etc etc
```

Here's a [blog article](https://medium.com/@thorntonbrenden/ruby-on-rails-switch-from-sqlite3-to-postgres-590009645c25) that covers what you need to change to switch from sqlite to Postgres in an existing project in more step-by-step fashion. Also note since you are using Heroku for production, the specification of database settings works a bit differently. See [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior) for a description of how Heroku PG configuration works.

Comment: Thank you very much!